# htaccess subdomain redirect and worpdress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, subdomain, subdirectory

After setting up Wordpress to use permalinks (which added some lines to my htaccess file), I got confused how to redirect a subdomain to a subfolder (`astro.aspiracoesquimicas.net` should redirect to `aspiracoesquimicas.net/astro`): what I had tried (and worked) before doesn't work anymore:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^astro\.aspiracoesquimicas\.net$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/astro/
RewriteRule (.*) /astro/$1
```

Now I get a 500 Internal Server Error with the subdomain. I don't know about htaccess configuring and don't understand what changed because of Wordpress.

I'd also like to redirect `blog.aspiracoesquimicas.net` to the main domain `aspiracoesquimicas.net`

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add the `L` flag to the rule and make sure you place the rules *BEFORE* the wordpress rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^astro\.aspiracoesquimicas\.net$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/astro/
RewriteRule (.*) /astro/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I tried the following:

`RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^astro\.aspiracoesquimicas\.net$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/astro/
RewriteRule (.*) /astro/$1 [L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress`

But still couldn't get it to work...

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On  .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^astro\.aspiracoesquimicas\.net/
ReWriteRule ^(.*)$ https://aspiracoesquimicas.net/astro/$1 [R=301,L]
```

use this method